# How to make electron menu to make a general search in the current window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, full-text-search

I'm looking for a way to create an electron menu with the label Find... & perform a general search in the current browser window. I was able to add the option, but I don't know how to access the browser to grab an element by ID. My current code:

```
const template = [  
  {
    label: 'Find..',
    click() {
      document.querySelector('#filter').focus()
      return console.log("Click working!")
    },
  },
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
return Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

Now I would like to do something like this on the click event:

```
document.querySelector('#filter').focus()
```

Basically, this `ID` belongs to a search `input` field that I want to add focus to. Unfortunately, the `document` or `window` is `undefined`.

Comment: Mmm. . . something like what? Seems like your question is cut off.

Comment: @NoGrabbing thanks I have updated my answer. I didn't realize it! Basically, I just need to access to the DOM to pick that element & do something with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, this ID belongs to a search input field that I want to add
>   focus to. Unfortunately, the document or window is undefined.

From `main`, you can get the active window easily enough ([docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow)):

```
let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
```

But I don't know how to access the window document directly. (Seems odd that it is not accessible). I suppose you can send an `IPC` message to the window – or use this [webContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) method:

```
contents.executeJavaScript(code[, userGesture])
```

Haven't ever needed to use the latter. Could work ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried `contents.executeJavaScript(code[, userGesture])` but it's also `undefined`. You have given me good tips!